# Tour of Heroes Tutorial app is over 2 MB's. Why does it run so slowly?

Tags: angular

I went through the tutorial on the Angular website, https://angular.io/tutorial, and found that when my browser loads this it is a total of 2.9 MB to finish loading the entire page.

I even enabled production mode to see if it would load faster but sadly it did not help much. Is there something i'm missing? Or is Angular mostly for large scale apps?

Comment: Did you compile with AOT?

Comment: @AntonLee I am looking into that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple angular app with AOT is usually around 150-200 kB.

If you just run your app using `ng serve` without using AOT, it is normal to have more than 2.9mb of files because you are in development mode and there are no optimizations applied to the app.
Something like this 
[image]

You can run `ng serve --prod` to see what your app looks like in production mode.

Here's a sample

[image]

Using just the `--prod` is now with AOT enabled.
More info: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds